# How to return the value of a column with the related row name? Using R or Bash

Tags: r

I have the following data.frame:

```
         x         y
row1     value1    GA:23456,GA:14777
row2     value2    
row3     value3    GA:15678
row4     value4    GA:15679,GA:14777
```

and I'd like to return the following output:

```
         x         y
row1     value1    GA:23456
row1     value1    GA:14777
row2     value2    
row3     value3    GA:15678
row4     value4    GA:15679
row4     value4    GA:14777
```

Thanks for the availability!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help you:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  separate_rows(y, sep = ",")

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  row   x      y       
  <chr> <chr>  <chr>   
1 row1  value1 GA:23456
2 row1  value1 GA:14777
3 row2  value2 NA      
4 row3  value3 GA:15678
5 row4  value4 GA:15679
6 row4  value4 GA:14777
```

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
    row                       x         y
row1     value1    GA:23456,GA:14777
row2     value2    NA
row3     value3    GA:15678
row4     value4    GA:15679,GA:14777 ")
```

Comment: `separate_rows` is best suited for these cases

Answer (score 1):

We could use `cSplit`

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df, 'y', sep = ",", 'long')
```